# My SQL Workbench crash when I want to save

Tags: windows-8, mysql, mysql-workbench

Sorry for bad grammar, first at all, English is not my native language. :)

First, I'd installed MySQL Workbench in my computer Windows 8.1, but when
I want to save like a model for example, Windows say this
"MySQL has stop, wait for Windows to find a soluction"

I have installed so many versions, but is the same  :(

Comment: Add error logs also to your question.

Comment: Please use [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html) to manage your MySQL products. Use it to install MySQL server, MySQL Workbench, and MySQL notifier. It also configures/manages them, confirms that you're using the latest version, and is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem : I'm french and my first name is "Dorothée". 
I create another account named 'admin', I connected to this account and then I launch Workbench.
It solved this problem doing that !

Hope it will help you and others ;)

Dorothée

Comment: So are you saying that the problem is using "international" characters in the account name?